# Calculating point to line distance in GLSL

Tags: geometry, glsl, webgl

I am trying to calculate a point to line distance in GSLS - precisely in turbo.js [turbo.js](https://turbo.js.org/)

This is part of a more general problem in which I try to find the [closest points on GeoJSON multiline] respective to a set of GeoJSON points - the number of calculations for a 500-points set on 1000 segments line ends up being 500k point-to-distance calculations.

This is way too much to handle in the browser (even in workers) so parallelism helps a lot.

The trick is that AFAIK I can only use a vec4 as an input, which means I can only do calculations on pairs of points.

So far I've progressed to calculating distance and bearing of all pairs - but can't make the last leg to calculating point-to-line distance.

So the question is - given 3 points a, b and c, and knowing

- their position in lon and lat
- their pairwise bearing and distance

Is it possible to calculate the distance from a to the line defined by b and c **using transforms that use vec2, vec3 or vec4 as input argument**?

As a sub-problem - I know how to calculate the distance if the height of the triangle (a, b, c) doesn't intersect the line (a, b) because it's min(distance(a, b), distance(a, c)).

But then, how do I calculate if it intersects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I implement the distance from a point to a line segment in GLSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246100/how-can-i-implement-the-distance-from-a-point-to-a-line-segment-in-glsl)

Comment: @LJᛃ - no, it doesn't, because the problem is how to go about it when the maximum number of input arguments for a function is 4 (the vec4 that gets pulled by `read()`x).

Comment: Hm okay, this isnt a `webgl` or `glsl` question then. As there's no tag for the library either  I'd say your best bet is to file an issue on the github of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question.

It sounds like for 500 input points you want to know, for 1000 line segments, for each point, which segment is closest.

If that's what you're asking then put all the points in a floating point textures (another word for a texture is a 2D array). Draw a -1 to +1 quad that's the size of the number of results (500 results so 50x10 or 25x20 etc..) Pass in the resolution of the textures. Use `gl_FragCoord` to calculate an index to get the input, A, and loop over all the other lines. Read the results via readPixels by encoding the index of the closest pair as a color.

```
  precision highp float;

  uniform sampler2D aValues;
  uniform vec2 aDimensions;  // the size of the aValues texture in pixels (texels)
  uniform sampler2D bValues;
  uniform vec2 bDimensions;  // the size of the bValues texture in pixels (texels)
  uniform sampler2D cValues;
  uniform vec2 cDimensions;  // the size of the cValues texture in pixels (texels)
  uniform vec2 outputDimensions; // the size of the thing we're drawing to (canvas)

  // this code, given a sampler2D, the size of the texture, and an index
  // computes a UV coordinate to pull one RGBA value out of a texture
  // as though the texture was a 1D array.
  vec3 getPoint(in sampler2D tex, in vec2 dimensions, in float index) {
    vec2 uv = (vec2(
       floor(mod(index, dimensions.x)),
       floor(index / dimensions.x)) + 0.5) / dimensions;
    return texture2D(tex, uv).xyz;
  }

  // from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6853926/128511
  float distanceFromPointToLine(in vec3 a, in vec3 b, in vec3 c) {
    vec3 ba = a - b;
    vec3 bc = c - b;
    float d = dot(ba, bc);
    float len = length(bc);
    float param = 0.0;
    if (len != 0.0) {
      param = clamp(d / (len * len), 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    vec3 r = b + bc * param;
    return distance(a, r);
  }

  void main() {
    // gl_FragCoord is the coordinate of the pixel that is being set by the fragment shader.
    // It is the center of the pixel so the bottom left corner pixel will be (0.5, 0.5).
    // the pixel to the left of that is (1.5, 0.5), The pixel above that is (0.5, 1.5), etc...
    // so we can compute back into a linear index 
    float ndx = floor(gl_FragCoord.y) * outputDimensions.x + floor(gl_FragCoord.x); 
    
    // find the closest points
    float minDist = 10000000.0; 
    float minIndex = -1.0;
    vec3 a = getPoint(aValues, aDimensions, ndx);
    for (int i = 0; i < ${bPoints.length / 4}; ++i) {
      vec3 b = getPoint(bValues, bDimensions, float(i));
      vec3 c = getPoint(cValues, cDimensions, float(i));
      float dist = distanceFromPointToLine(a, b, c);
      if (dist < minDist) {
        minDist = dist;
        minIndex = float(i);
      }
    }
    
    // convert to 8bit color. The canvas defaults to RGBA 8bits per channel
    // so take our integer index (minIndex) and convert to float values that
    // will end up as the same 32bit index when read via readPixels as
    // 32bit values.
    gl_FragColor = vec4(
      mod(minIndex, 256.0),
      mod(floor(minIndex / 256.0), 256.0),
      mod(floor(minIndex / (256.0 * 256.0)), 256.0) ,
      floor(minIndex / (256.0 * 256.0 * 256.0))) / 255.0;
  }
```

I'm only going to guess though that in general this is better solved with some spatial structure that somehow makes it so you don't have to check every line with every point but something like the code above should work and be very parallel. Each result will be computed by another GPU core.

```js
const v3 = twgl.v3;

// note: I'm using twgl to make the code smaller.
// This is not lesson in WebGL. You should already know what it means
// to setup buffers and attributes and set uniforms and create textures.
// What's important is the technique, not the minutia of WebGL. If you
// don't know how to do those things you need a much bigger tutorial
// on WebGL like https://webglfundamentals.org

function main() {
  const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  const ext = gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
  if (!ext) {
    alert('need OES_texture_float');
    return;
  }
  
  const r = max => Math.random() * max;
  const hsl = (h, s, l) => `hsl(${h * 360},${s * 100 | 0}%,${l * 100 | 0}%)`;
  function createPoints(numPoints) {
    const points = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i) {
      points.push(r(300), r(150), 0, 0);  // RGBA
    }
    return points;
  }

  function distanceFromPointToLineSquared(a, b, c) {
    const ba = v3.subtract(a, b);
    const bc = v3.subtract(c, b);
    const dot = v3.dot(ba, bc);
    const lenSq = v3.lengthSq(bc);
    let param = 0;
    if (lenSq !== 0) {
      param = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, dot / lenSq));
    }
    const r = v3.add(b, v3.mulScalar(bc, param));
    return v3.distanceSq(a, r);
  }

  const aPoints = createPoints(6);
  const bPoints = createPoints(15);
  const cPoints = createPoints(15);
  
  // do it in JS to check
  {
    // compute closest lines to points
    const closest = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < aPoints.length; i += 4) {
      const a = aPoints.slice(i, i + 3);
      let minDistSq = Number.MAX_VALUE;
      let minIndex = -1;
      for (let j = 0; j < bPoints.length; j += 4) {
        const b = bPoints.slice(j, j + 3);
        const c = cPoints.slice(j, j + 3);
        const distSq = distanceFromPointToLineSquared(a, b, c);
        if (distSq < minDistSq) {
          minDistSq = distSq;
          minIndex = j / 4;
        }
      }
      closest.push(minIndex);
    }

    drawResults(document.querySelector('#js'), closest);
  }

  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = position;
  }
  `;
  
  const fs = `
  precision highp float;

  uniform sampler2D aValues;
  uniform vec2 aDimensions;  // the size of the aValues texture in pixels (texels)
  uniform sampler2D bValues;
  uniform vec2 bDimensions;  // the size of the bValues texture in pixels (texels)
  uniform sampler2D cValues;
  uniform vec2 cDimensions;  // the size of the cValues texture in pixels (texels)
  uniform vec2 outputDimensions; // the size of the thing we're drawing to (canvas)

  // this code, given a sampler2D, the size of the texture, and an index
  // computes a UV coordinate to pull one RGBA value out of a texture
  // as though the texture was a 1D array.
  vec3 getPoint(in sampler2D tex, in vec2 dimensions, in float index) {
    vec2 uv = (vec2(
       floor(mod(index, dimensions.x)),
       floor(index / dimensions.x)) + 0.5) / dimensions;
    return texture2D(tex, uv).xyz;
  }

  // from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6853926/128511
  float distanceFromPointToLine(in vec3 a, in vec3 b, in vec3 c) {
    vec3 ba = a - b;
    vec3 bc = c - b;
    float d = dot(ba, bc);
    float len = length(bc);
    float param = 0.0;
    if (len != 0.0) {
      param = clamp(d / (len * len), 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    vec3 r = b + bc * param;
    return distance(a, r);
  }

  void main() {
    // gl_FragCoord is the coordinate of the pixel that is being set by the fragment shader.
    // It is the center of the pixel so the bottom left corner pixel will be (0.5, 0.5).
    // the pixel to the left of that is (1.5, 0.5), The pixel above that is (0.5, 1.5), etc...
    // so we can compute back into a linear index 
    float ndx = floor(gl_FragCoord.y) * outputDimensions.x + floor(gl_FragCoord.x); 
    
    // find the closest points
    float minDist = 10000000.0; 
    float minIndex = -1.0;
    vec3 a = getPoint(aValues, aDimensions, ndx);
    for (int i = 0; i < ${bPoints.length / 4}; ++i) {
      vec3 b = getPoint(bValues, bDimensions, float(i));
      vec3 c = getPoint(cValues, cDimensions, float(i));
      float dist = distanceFromPointToLine(a, b, c);
      if (dist < minDist) {
        minDist = dist;
        minIndex = float(i);
      }
    }
    
    // convert to 8bit color. The canvas defaults to RGBA 8bits per channel
    // so take our integer index (minIndex) and convert to float values that
    // will end up as the same 32bit index when read via readPixels as
    // 32bit values.
    gl_FragColor = vec4(
      mod(minIndex, 256.0),
      mod(floor(minIndex / 256.0), 256.0),
      mod(floor(minIndex / (256.0 * 256.0)), 256.0) ,
      floor(minIndex / (256.0 * 256.0 * 256.0))) / 255.0;
  }
  `;
  
  // compile shader, link program, lookup locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
  
  // calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for a -1 to +1 quad
  const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createXYQuadBufferInfo(gl);

  // make an RGBA float texture for each set of points
  // calls gl.createTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.texImage2D, gl.texParameteri
  const aTex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
    src: aPoints,
    width: aPoints.length / 4,
    type: gl.FLOAT,
    minMag: gl.NEAREST,
  });
  const bTex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
    src: bPoints,
    width: bPoints.length / 4,
    type: gl.FLOAT,
    minMag: gl.NEAREST,
  });
  const cTex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
    src: cPoints,
    width: cPoints.length / 4,
    type: gl.FLOAT,
    minMag: gl.NEAREST,
  });
    
  const numOutputs = aPoints.length / 4;
  gl.canvas.width = numOutputs;
  gl.canvas.height = 1;
  gl.viewport(0, 0, numOutputs, 1);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);  
  
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniform
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    aValues: aTex,
    aDimensions: [aPoints.length / 4, 1],
    bValues: cTex,
    bDimensions: [bPoints.length / 4, 1],
    cValues: bTex,
    cDimensions: [cPoints.length / 4, 1],
    outputDimensions: [aPoints.length / 4, 1],
  });
  
  // draw the quad
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  
  // get result
  const pixels = new Uint8Array(numOutputs * 4);
  const results = new Uint32Array(pixels.buffer);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, numOutputs, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
  drawResults(document.querySelector('#glsl'), results);


  function drawResults(canvas, closest) {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    // draw the lines
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (let j = 0; j < bPoints.length; j += 4) {
      const b = bPoints.slice(j, j + 2);
      const c = cPoints.slice(j, j + 2);
      ctx.moveTo(...b);
      ctx.lineTo(...c);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#888';
    ctx.stroke();
    
    // draw the points and closest lines
    for (let i = 0; i < aPoints.length; i += 4) {
      const a = aPoints.slice(i, i + 2);
      const ndx = closest[i / 4] * 4;
      const b = bPoints.slice(ndx, ndx + 2);
      const c = cPoints.slice(ndx, ndx + 2);
      const color = hsl(i / aPoints.length, 1, 0.4);
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(a[0] - 2, a[1] - 2, 5, 5);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(...b);
      ctx.lineTo(...c);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }

}
main();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<div>glsl</div>
<canvas id="glsl"></canvas>
<div>js</div>
<canvas id="js"></canvas>
```

If you use WebGL2 then you can use `texelFetch` so `getPoint` becomes

```
vec3 getPoint(in sampler2D tex, in int index) {
  ivec2 size = textureSize(tex, 0);
  ivec2 uv = ivec2(index % size.x, index / size.x);
  return texelFetch(tex, uv, 0).xyz;
}
```

and you don't need to pass in the size of the input textures, only the output size. Also you could make your output R32U and output unsigned integer indices so no need to encode the result.

note: The code assumes you are doing less then 2048 values for each a, b and c so much of the code assumes 1 dimensional textures. If you need more than 2048 you'll need to adjust the code to make rectangular textures of a size that fits your data for example if you had 9000 values then a 9x1000 texture would work. If you have 8999 values then you still need a 9x1000 texture just padded to make a rectangle since textures are 2D arrays.

Also note that calling readPixels is considered slow. For example, if you just wanted to draw the results as above, instead of rendering to the canvas and reading the values out via readPixels you could render the result to a texture, then pass the texture into another shader.

---

## addendum

This is probably the wrong place for this but as a terse explanation of GLSL for stuff like this you can think of GLSL as a fancy version of `Array.prototype.map`. When you use `map` you don't choose what is being written to directly. It happens indirectly.

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const b = a.map((v, index) => { return v * 2 + index; });
```

The `{ return v * 2 + index}` part is analogous to a shader. In JavaScript the function inside map returns in value. in GLSL ES 1.0 the shader sets `gl_FragColor` as the output. In the Javascript `index` is the index of the array being written to (and happens to be the index of the input array as well). In GLSL `gl_FragCoord` serves the same role.

Otherwise, the output of the vertex shader determines which pixels (which array elements of a 2D array) will get written to so that makes it a more selective version of `map`. In the code above we're drawing a -1 to +1 quad effectively saying "map over all pixels".

In fact here's a version of the above code, no GLSL, just JavaScript, but the JavaScript re-structured to look more like GLSL.

```js
const v3 = twgl.v3;

function main() {
  
  const r = max => Math.random() * max;
  const hsl = (h, s, l) => `hsl(${h * 360},${s * 100 | 0}%,${l * 100 | 0}%)`;

  function createPoints(numPoints) {
    const points = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i) {
      points.push(r(300), r(150), 0, 0);  // RGBA
    }
    return points;
  }

  function distanceFromPointToLineSquared(a, b, c) {
    const ba = v3.subtract(a, b);
    const bc = v3.subtract(c, b);
    const dot = v3.dot(ba, bc);
    const lenSq = v3.lengthSq(bc);
    let param = 0;
    if (lenSq !== 0) {
      param = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, dot / lenSq));
    }
    const r = v3.add(b, v3.mulScalar(bc, param));
    return v3.distanceSq(a, r);
  }

  const aPoints = createPoints(6);
  const bPoints = createPoints(15);
  const cPoints = createPoints(15);
  
  const gl_FragCoord = {};
  let gl_FragColor;
  
  const aValues = aPoints;
  const aDimensions = {}; // N/A
  const bValues = bPoints;
  const bDimensions = {}; // N/A
  const cValues = cPoints;
  const cDimensions = {}; // N/A
  const outputDimensions = {x: aPoints.length / 4, y: 1 };
  
  function getPoint(sampler, dimension, ndx) {
    return sampler.slice(ndx * 4, ndx * 4 + 3);
  }
  
  function javaScriptFragmentShader() {
    // gl_FragCoord is the coordinate of the pixel that is being set by the fragment shader.
    // It is the center of the pixel so the bottom left corner pixel will be (0.5, 0.5).
    // the pixel to the left of that is (1.5, 0.5), The pixel above that is (0.5, 1.5), etc...
    // so we can compute back into a linear index 
    const ndx = Math.floor(gl_FragCoord.y) * outputDimensions.x + Math.floor(gl_FragCoord.x); 
    
    // find the closest points
    let minDist = 10000000.0; 
    let minIndex = -1.0;
    const a = getPoint(aValues, aDimensions, ndx);
    for (let i = 0; i < bPoints.length / 4; ++i) {
      const b = getPoint(bValues, bDimensions, i);
      const c = getPoint(cValues, cDimensions, i);
      const dist = distanceFromPointToLineSquared(a, b, c);
      if (dist < minDist) {
        minDist = dist;
        minIndex = i;
      }
    }
    
    // convert to 8bit color. The canvas defaults to RGBA 8bits per channel
    // so take our integer index (minIndex) and convert to float values that
    // will end up as the same 32bit index when read via readPixels as
    // 32bit values.
    gl_FragColor = [
      minIndex % 256.0,
      Math.floor(minIndex / 256.0) % 256.0,
      Math.floor(minIndex / (256.0 * 256.0)) % 256.0,
      Math.floor(minIndex / (256.0 * 256.0 * 256.0)),
    ].map(v => v / 255.0);
  }
  
  // do it in JS to check
  {
    // compute closest lines to points
    
    const closest = [];
    const width = aPoints.length / 4;
    const height = 1;
    
    // WebGL drawing each pixel
    for (let y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
      for (let x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        gl_FragCoord.x = x + 0.5;  // because pixels represent a rectangle one unit wide in pixel space
        gl_FragCoord.y = y + 0.5;  // so the center of each pixel in the middle of that rectangle
        javaScriptFragmentShader();
        const index = gl_FragColor[0] * 255 +
                      gl_FragColor[1] * 255 * 256 +
                      gl_FragColor[2] * 255 * 256 * 256 +
                      gl_FragColor[3] * 255 * 256 * 256 * 256;
        closest.push(index);
      }
    }

    drawResults(document.querySelector('#js'), closest);
  }

  function drawResults(canvas, closest) {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    // draw the lines
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (let j = 0; j < bPoints.length; j += 4) {
      const b = bPoints.slice(j, j + 2);
      const c = cPoints.slice(j, j + 2);
      ctx.moveTo(...b);
      ctx.lineTo(...c);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#888';
    ctx.stroke();
    
    // draw the points and closest lines
    for (let i = 0; i < aPoints.length; i += 4) {
      const a = aPoints.slice(i, i + 2);
      const ndx = closest[i / 4] * 4;
      const b = bPoints.slice(ndx, ndx + 2);
      const c = cPoints.slice(ndx, ndx + 2);
      const color = hsl(i / aPoints.length, 1, 0.4);
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(a[0] - 2, a[1] - 2, 5, 5);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(...b);
      ctx.lineTo(...c);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }

}
main();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="js"></canvas>
```

Comment: I suspect you understood my question correctly, I wish I could say the same about your answer which is far above and beyond my current level of understanding in GLSL. I'll study and accept it in the next days - thanks a lot!

Comment: What part are you having difficulty understanding? Added some comments. Also [here's some WebGL tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org)

Comment: it's a case of it's not you, it's me. I get the general concepts and ideas, but I'm not familiar with GLSL yet, so some of the concepts remain obscure for now. Unfortunately the part I'm least clear about is reading/writing data. I'll dig through the tutorials as soon as I can. I'm already grateful for this answer and others you've given me in the past

Comment: Yes, I understand that you're not that familiar with GLSL. I added some more stuff just in case. I know it's not as simple as a few paragraphs of explanation but maybe it will be helpful.